# Starting Selenium on Linux dumps hundreds of lines of unsuccessful connection attempt of chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

When I start my Selenium application, it writes to the standard output hundreds of unsuccessful connection attempt before within 1-2 seconds it succeeds.

```
Connection refused (localhost:33631)
... hundreds within 1-2 sec...
Connection refused (localhost:33631)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

I am starting Selenium with the following C# code, the exact same code in the exact same project in Windows build works without this eager connect issue:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("hide-crash-restore-bubble"); // This can help to disable the "Restore pages?" popup
options.AddArgument("disable-infobars"); // This can also help to disable other popups
options.AddArgument("noerrdialogs");
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=mydir");
options.AddArgument("remote-debugging-port=9230");
var path = ""; // chromedriver is in the same folder as the executable  
var driver = new ChromeDriver(path, options);
```

I suppose, Selenium launches google-chrome (which starts slower) and chromedriver (which start faster), then chromedriver tries to connect, but at this time google-chrome is not yet listening. The 1-2 sec startup time is fine by me,
but the zillion lines of Connection refused totally scrolls out the meaningful messages.

Is there any way to get a rid off those messages?

Comment: you should include your driver initialization code.

Comment: Show us your code please (or at least a minimal reproducible example). Are you working in Python, Java or something else? Is Selenium running in Docker container or directly on host?

Comment: you are right, I edited the question. However I do not think the code will bring the answer, as ii runs without issue on Windows. Also there is no functional issue on Linux neither (as the chromedriver connects successfully within 2 seconds, just get the rid of this too agile connection urge